# How can I photograph reflective surfaces without the camera being visible?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting, reflection, texture

I want to make some *grunge maps* (surface imperfection overlay graphics for 3D rendering) by photographing **flat** (not round) real-world surfaces. However, when I try to take pictures of reflective surfaces like windows and countertops that have fingerprints and scratches, I end up lots of ugly reflections of the photographer (me).

Here is an example of a grunge map https://www.poliigon.com/texture/1596

Is there some kind of studio set up that allows you to take pictures of surface imperfections without reflections or transparency interfering? I have a DSLR, but I don't really think that the camera or lens should matter too much.

Comment: Sounds interesting but I do not understand what is that. Is it to overlay bumps in a 3D program?

Comment: Yeah, its for making things look more realistic in 3D programs like blender

Comment: You might find this question and answers relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47667/25407

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take pictures of reflective spherical objects?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30853/how-to-take-pictures-of-reflective-spherical-objects)

Comment: @Caleb This is for flat objects, with the intent of photographing the objects imperfection instead of the object.

Comment: This is a common problem in macro photography.  Most solutions there involve using light splitters.  Other ideas in answers to these similar questions: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3602/27832, http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/61106/27832

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Put your glass vertically so that you can see through it (A).
- Put a piece of black cloth far away behind the glass (B).
- Put a flash on top of the glass, almost  (C).
- Use some cardboard or some reflective surface so the light only illuminates the glass (D).
- Put the camera out of the light. The light from the flash is much greater than the light coming from your direction and overpowers the reflection (E).

Take a look at this setup. It is similar, the only difference is that in this case you DO want a dirty glass so in this case,  you illuminate only the glass: [Low-key photo suggestions for fish?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76981/low-key-photo-suggestions-for-fish/84773#84773)

- You do not need a diffused light, but the idea is the same.

[image]

Comment: Make a diagram or something? You explanation is a little bit confusing.

Comment: You did not make your homework and check the other post. Ok, I did mine. n_n

Comment: The diagram helps a lot. I will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

One traditional way to avoid reflections is with a shift [or tilt/shift] lens. The camera is parallel to but off axis with the reflective surface. Then the lens is shifted toward the mirror to capture a straight on view.

More about the technique [here](http://www.popphoto.com/how-to/2011/05/complete-guide-to-tiltshift-photography#page-5). And how to build your own [here](http://cow.mooh.org/projects/tiltshift/diyexamples.html) for the adventurous.

Comment: Oh wow! Thats pretty cool. I will look into this. Its a bit more expensive than a lighting setup, but would be cool to include in my arsenal of lenses

Comment: @10Replies A medium or large format film camera with a bellows is another option for achieving the same sort of photographic effect.

Comment: Yeap, good tip ben rudges!. @10 Replies, keep in mind that this is to complement. The light setup not only is to get rid of the reflection, but to increase the texture of your imperfections.

Comment: If you have pixels to spare (i.e., don't mind cropping), you can try this out with just a wide angle lens, without any shift capability or shift adapters. Setup your lighting as you would, and point your camera perpendicular to the surface. But offset your camera so that the area you want to capture is offset to one side in the viewfinder, or towards a corner, such that the camera's reflection is not in the crop area. Then after taking the image, just crop the photo to that area. Effectively, that is the same result as a shifted lens.

Comment: @scottbb But then I wouldn't wind up with new awesome optics.

Comment: @benrudgers lol. I'd shake my head, but I've made more expensive decisions for lesser justifications. I'm certainly not one to lecture on this count! =)